# trigger jenkins build after SVN commit

Tags: svn, batch-file, vbscript, jenkins

I have a small issue regarding the Jenkins build after SVN commit.
i have configured a jenkins.vb script to call after the post-commit hook, but the build is not triggering after the commit.

When i pass the Repository path and revision # through command line , the build gets triggered.

Can any one help me out of this issue. please find below the post-commit hook and jenkins.vbs file
Jenkins Url to trigger build : http:\server-name\job\branchname\build?delay=2sec

**post commit hook :**

```
@echo on
rem POST-COMMIT HOOK
set REPOS=%1
set REV=%2
SET CSCRIPT=C:\WINNT\system32\cscript.exe
SET VBSCRIPT=D:\SVN\hooks\post-commit-hook-jenkins.vbs
SET SVNLOOK=C:\Subversion\bin\svnlook.exe %VBSCRIPT% %REPOS% %REV%
```

**Jenkins.vbs**

```
repos   = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
rev     = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
svnlook = "C:\Subversion\bin\svnlook.exe"
jenkinsBaseUrl = **JenkinsURL** (unable to paste the URL would be in this format "URL:8080")
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set uuidExec = shell.Exec(svnlook & " uuid " & repos)
Do Until uuidExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
  uuid = uuidExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop
' Create a list of all branches that have been modified.
Dim branches()
ReDim Preserve branches(-1)
Set changedExec = shell.Exec(svnlook & " changed --revision " & rev & " " & repos)
Do Until changedExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
  fileChanged = changedExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
  ' Get the branch names if any
  If InStr(fileChanged, "source/branches/") Then
    branchStartIndex = InStr(fileChanged, "source/branches/") + 38
    branch = Mid(fileChanged, branchStartIndex)
    branchEndIndex = InStr(branch, "/") - 1
    branch = Left(branch, branchEndIndex)
    branchFound = False
    For count = 0 to UBound(branches)
        If (CStr(branches(count)) = CStr(branch)) Then
            branchFound = True
        End If
    Next

    ' Add the branch if it was not previously added
    If branchFound = False Then
        ReDim Preserve branches(UBound(branches) + 1)
        branches(UBound(branches)) = branch
    End If
  End If
Loop
' the above code gives the branch name in which the check-in has been done (THE ABOVE CODE WORKS FINE)
' Fire out a build for every branch that has changed
For count = LBound(branches) to UBound(branches)
    url = jenkinsBaseUrl + "/job/" & branches(count) & "/build?delay=0sec"
    Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    http.open "POST", url, False
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
    http.send changed
Next
```

Comment: Is it really *that* time-critical to trigger the build? I'd just use Jenkins' built-in SCM trigger...

Comment: you mean "build?delay=0sec".. this is not very important. but i am able to pass parameters via command line and it runs sucessfull & can you guide me regarding Jenkins built-in SCM trigger

Comment: No, I mean using a post-commit hook. Jenkins can detect changes in the repository by itself. In the configuration of your project(s), look for the ["Source Code Management"](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Configure-SVN-For-Jenkins-Job.png) and ["Build Triggers"](http://nerdwin15.com/files/uploads/2013/04/stash-jenkins-poll-scm.png) sections, you can set it all up in there.

Comment: to add more clarity, in my repository i have 40 branches and i have configured 40 Jobs where my requirement is if there is any change in any of the branch in repository, it should go to that job and trigger the build. in source code management do i need to give the URL of that branch and in build triggers section is it necessary to poll, because i am launching the URL "jenkinsBaseUrl + "/job/" & branches(count) & "/build?delay=0sec" if there are any cheanges in that branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the url to the repository (with the full path the specific branch) that you want to use in "Source Code Management", as discussed in the comments.

You *can* use polling if you want, which will have check all paths specified for new changes, at the specified regular intervals and trigger a new build when a new revision is detected.

Using a post-commit hook works just as well, and might be even necessary, e.g. if you don't want to constantly poll the repository for changes (maybe because the changes are infrequent), or if you need to specify multiple paths under Source Code Management that are needed for the project, but you don't want to trigger a build for changes in some of them.

The wiki page of the [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin#SubversionPlugin-Windowsspecificpostcommithook) provides some nice examples for post-commit hooks, including a VBScript - note that it doesn't use the build trigger url as you did in your script, but notifies the jenkins server of the commit to the specific svn repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have resolved by calling the another batch file by refering to the VB script... and it works fine...